# assistance with finding the High and low of an array and setting an array equal to zero

Tags: c

The problem i have is even though i set the array called exam[] to zero in main, when i call the function displayAllExam() only some are set to zero and others are set to random numbers that probably represent spaces in ram. This is messing up my displayExamAverage() function because when i run the code i can add values to the array but if i dont add 50 values then there will be random numbers in there. Also im really stuck on the displayHighLow function which is ment to find the highest and lowest value of the array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define pause system("pause")
#define cls system("cls")
#define flush fflush(stdin)
#define SIZE 50

//Lets Prototype
int getChoice();
void displayMenu();
void addScores(int a[],int *c);
void displayAllExam(int a[]);
void displayExamAverage(int a[], int *c);
void displayHighLow(int a[], int *c);


main(){
    int exams[SIZE] = {0}, counter = 0;
    char choice;
    do {
        choice = getChoice();
        switch(choice){
        case 1:
            addScores(&exams[SIZE],&counter);
            break;
        case 2:
            displayExamAverage(&exams[SIZE],&counter);
            break;
        case 3:
            displayHighLow(&exams[SIZE], &counter);
            break;
        case 4:
            displayAllExam(&exams[SIZE]);
            break;
        }

    }while (choice != 5);
}//end main

 int getChoice(){
    int result = 0;
    do{
        displayMenu();
        scanf_s("%i", &result);
        if(result < 1 || result >5 ){
            printf("Invalid Selection, please enter a number between 1 and 5\n");
        pause;}
    } while(result < 1 || result > 5);
    return result;
}//end getChoice

void displayMenu() {
    cls;
    printf("MAIN MENU\n\n");
    printf("1: add an exam score\n");
    printf("2.Display exam average\n");
    printf("3.Display High and Low score\n");
    printf("4.Display all scores\n");
    printf("5.Quit\n\n");
    printf("Enter your choice: \n\n");
    return;
}//end display menu

void addScores(int a[SIZE],int *c){
    int i=0;
    printf("please enter your score..");
    scanf_s("%i", &a[i]);
}//end add scores

void displayExamAverage(int a[],int *c){
    float average, total = 0.0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < *c; i++)
        total = total + a[i];
     average = total/ *c;
     printf("%f",average);
     pause;
}//end displayExamAverage

void displayHighLow(int a[],int *c){
    int high= a[0], low= a[0];
    int i,x,y;
    for(i=0; i < *c; i++){
        if(a[*c]> a[0])
            high = a[i];
    }
    for(i=0; i < *c; i++){
            if(a[*c]<a[0])
            low = a[i];
    }
    printf("The low is %i", low);
    printf("The high is %i", high);
    pause;

}//end DisplayHighLow

void displayAllExam(int a[SIZE]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i < SIZE; i++)
        printf("the %i score is %i\n",i+1,a[i]);
    pause;
}//end displayAllExam
```

Comment: Did you bother reading and understanding the answers to your previous question (which was clearly about the same topic) before launching into another question? Your `addScores` function is horribly broken - both in how it is called, and how you use it. You pass a pointer `c` that you don't use, and give it the address of a point past the end of the array `exams` as a starting point. Time to read up on pointers in C...

Comment: after posting the question and getting answers i thought the add scores problem was solved because one of the answers worked for me..  since i thought that was solved i posted a new question about the whole thing to see what was wrong with the entire picture

Comment: If the problem was solved, you should really mark it as "solved" and/or leave some comments to that effect. As it is, you look like you don't care for the answers given; and the current question doesn't give the impression you learnt anything from the earlier answers. You are getting people giving of their time and expertise freely - show your appreciation by responding, learning, and ultimately giving back.

Comment: These were my first 2 posts here so i really dont know how this place works yet. I guess i learned the hard way? Sorry for coming off as rude i honestly didnt know you guys wanted feedback. But i guess its human to want feedback when your helping someone.  i definitely should have reply=ied or even just post the whole code there. i'll remember for next time

Comment: That's OK. If a question is answered for you, you click the little check mark to "accept" it. And you try to show in your follow up question that you learned something. Maybe you even leave a link to the new question as a comment in the earlier one. Yes you are dealing with humans at the other end! People who want to help, and like to know that their efforts are appreciated. It is the only reward they get...

Comment: okay will do, and that sounds reasonable, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a pointer to the position just after the end of the array.  That's a big no-no, if you plan to read or write to it:

```
displayAllExam(&exams[SIZE]);
```

Instead, just pass it like this:

```
displayAllExam(exams);
```

Same goes for all your other calls.

Comment: OMG thank you soo much!! I will remember not to do that from now on!